# Trying to set a variable from a function, and check if it's false in the same line

Tags: php

I am trying to set a variable from a function, and then check if it is false in the same line. If it is false, I want to execute some code.

The code I have is the following:

```
  if ($wordid = wordnet_get_wordid_from_word($word) == FALSE) {
db_set_active();
    return $word;
  }
```

However it appears that `$wordid` is not getting set by this.

I've seen something like this being used before, and I've tested that inside the function, the value returned is NOT empty.

So what am I doing wrong here? Is it not possible to set a variable on the same line as you check whether it is false?

Comment: Put brackets around the assignment, does that do the trick for you? (`($wordid = wordnet_get_wordid_from_word($word)) == FALSE`)

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wordis` *is* getting set in this code. If you do an `echo gettype($wordis)` after the `if` you'll find it's a boolean. It's value will be the outcome of evaluating this: `wordnet_get_wordid_from_word($word) == FALSE`. Remember, if that evaluates `false` it'll skip the if statement anyway, that's probably why you think it's not working.

If you want `$wordid = wordnet_get_wordid_from_word($word)` and to check if that's false, use brackets:

`if (($wordid = wordnet_get_wordid_from_word($word)) == FALSE) {..`

IMO, confusing code. Separate it out.

Comment: And why does OP has to put brackets around the assignment?

Comment: It tell the parser to first evaluate the part in brackets. So it'll assign `$wordid` the output of the `wordnet_..` function. Otherwise it assigns it the evaluation of `wordnet_.. == FALSE`

Comment: And why does it assign the evaluation of `wordnet_.. == FALSE ` ?

Comment: That's just the rules of the parser. I suppose it sees the `=` and decides to assign to it everything on the right hand side, which in this case, is a logical comparison between FALSE the output of a function. Adding the brackets will tell the parser to evaluate the bracket contents first.

Comment: It's `Operator Precedence` just FYI. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
function test() {
    return false;
}

if( !$var = test() ) {
    echo "it's false";
} else {
    echo "it's true";
}
```

Output: `it's false`

> Is it not possible to set a variable on the same line as you check
>   whether it is false?

The above shows that it can be done.

Another example:

```
function hello() {
    return 'hello';
}

if( !$var = hello() ) {
    echo "it's false" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "it's true" . PHP_EOL;
}


var_dump( $var );
```

Outputs: `it's true string(5) "hello"`